# How to install postman client in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: google-chrome, postman

I downloaded latest postman 64bit file from [official site](https://www.getpostman.com/apps)

How to run .tar file and install postman in my system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use following code to download the latest file and install. You don't need to download file from Postman's official site. Just run following commands on terminal and you will get latest postman client

```
wget https://dl.pstmn.io/download/latest/linux64 -O postman.tar.gz
sudo tar -xzf postman.tar.gz -C /opt
rm postman.tar.gz
sudo ln -s /opt/Postman/Postman /usr/bin/postman
```

After runing above commands; run one last command that will show you in search panel

```
cat > ~/.local/share/applications/postman.desktop <<EOL
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Postman
Exec=postman
Icon=/opt/Postman/resources/app/assets/icon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Development;
EOL
```

I think that will help you.

Answer (score 6):

Or if you use snap packages:

```
sudo snap install postman
```